# How to document a regular expression in itself?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regular expression [e.g. at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pK3jX9/1)

```
(\/+[^\/\[\]]+(?:\[[^\]']*(?:'[^']*')\])?)+
```

I have verified that it matches my test string

```
//SapButton[@automationId='tbar[0]/btn[15]']
```

Since the Regex cannot be understood rightaway, I tried the documentation feature using `(?#)`, so I changed the Regex to [also at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xW0aL2/1)

```
((?# Capturing group for the type name)
\/+(?# Start with / or // )
[^\/\[\]]+(?# Type name exclusing start of attribute and next type)
(?:(?# Non-capturing group for the attribute)
\[(?# Start of an attribute)
[^\]']*(?# Anything but end of attribute or start of string)
(?:(?# non-capturing group for string)
'(?# string start)
[^']*(?# anything inside the string, except end of string)
'(?# string end)
)(?# end of string group)
\](?# end of attribute)
)?(?# Attribute can occur 0 or one time)
)+(?# Type can occur once or many times)
```

But now the regex does not match my test string any more. The reason are the newlines. Changing the Regex to

```
((?# Capturing group for the type name)\/+(?# Start with / or // )[^\/\[\]]+(?# Type name exclusing start of attribute and next type)(?:(?# Non-capturing group for the attribute)\[(?# Start of an attribute)[^\]']*(?# Anything but end of attribute or start of string)(?:(?# non-capturing group for string)'(?# string start)[^']*(?# anything inside the string, except end of string)'(?# string end))(?# end of string group)\](?# end of attribute))?(?# Attribute can occur 0 or one time))+(?# Type can occur once or many times)
```

works. But it is unreadable again.

**How do I document a regular expression in itself properly?**

Note that I want to avoid doing it in the comment of the C# method since this has too much potential for not being updated when the regex is changed.

IMHO, it would be best done in a verbatim string with multiple lines (but it still has to work, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [Ignore White Space option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Whitespace)

The problem is that then you'll have to escape spaces and `#` with a `\`. The good news is that `#` will begin a comment, like `//` in C#

You can activate it with `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` or with `(?x)` at the beginning of the regex.

`(?x)` is supported by https://regex101.com/

Comment: Does that differ from the `x` option at Regex101, which is already enabled?

Comment: Obviously it does. Using `IgnorePatternWhitespace ` in C# works. I was relying to much on Regex101.

Comment: @Thomas I've just tested the `(?x)` in regex101 and it works correctly (and you can use it even in C#)

Comment: Yes, it seems that the `gmixXsuUAJ` is only a reference list and those are not applied to the regular expression. That was totally misleading.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't exactly a desirable solution, but you can store your documented regexp in a String and, before match, you can replace all \r\n from your String.

Then, you will have a readable representation in your code, and a correct regexp at runtime.

I don't know other way, but what you with is laudable.

Regards